# Setting up Recycler View in Kotlin, and don't understand how methods are being called on recyclerView variable without it being instantiated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm sure this is extremely simple, but I've been away from Android for a while and new to Kotlin as well, so I'm not sure what I'm looking at.

I'm following tutorials online to set up recycler view, and I always see a recyclerView varaible with methods like .apply and .layoutManager being called on it.

The problem is that I don't see where recyclerView is initialized (or imported?), and in my app I'm getting a red underline on it with 'unresolved reference error'.

Here's the full main activity of the setup I'm trying to reproduce from a StackOverflow answer.

[Trying to create a simple recyclerView in Kotlin, but the adapter is not applying properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43012903/trying-to-create-a-simple-recyclerview-in-kotlin-but-the-adapter-is-not-applyin)

To me, in the below example, recyclerView seems to be getting used out of nowhere. What is going on?

````
import android.os.Bundle
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.view.Window
import android.view.WindowManager
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import net.simplifiedcoding.recyclerviewexample.CustomAdapter


class MainActivity : Activity() {


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val users = ArrayList<Model_Details>()
        users.add(Model_Details("Kaju katli", "Kaju katli, also known as kaju Katari or kaju barfi, is an Indian dessert similar to a barfi.",R.drawable.kaju))
        users.add(Model_Details("Doughnut", "The doughnut is popular in many countries and prepared in various forms as a sweet snack that can be homemade or purchased in bakeries, supermarkets, food stalls, and franchised specialty outlets",R.drawable.donuts))
        users.add(Model_Details("Panna cotta", "Panna cotta is an Italian dessert of sweetened cream thickened with gelatin and molded. The cream may be aromatized with rum, coffee, vanilla, or other flavorings.",R.drawable.panna_cotta))
        users.add(Model_Details("Rose Cookies", "Rose cooky is a famous South Indian snack made during festivals",R.drawable.rosecookies))
        users.add(Model_Details("Belgian waffle", "In North America, Belgian waffles are a variety of waffle with a lighter batter, larger squares, and deeper pockets than ordinary American waffles",R.drawable.belgianwaffle))

        val obj_adapter = CustomAdapter(users)

        recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayout.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView.adapter = obj_adapter
    }


}
```
````

Comment: is it getting imported here import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_main.* ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you're using **Kotlin synthetics**, but Kotlin Android Extensions is deprecated. The recommendation is use [view binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding). Link to migrate [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration).

Comment: FYI it's called "synthetic sugar', not just "synthetic".